# Applications like Chrome look blurry in Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1

After installing Windows 8.1 update, a lot of applications, like Chrome, Skype, etc. looks blurry. How do I fix it?

For example, (bigger image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MM3ig.png)):

[image: Blurry windows]

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://serverfault.com/questions/570785/how-can-i-make-microsoft-management-console-high-dpi-aware-in-windows-8-1

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Fix: You should disable scaling by opening properties of the application/short cut.

[image: Disable scaling]

Even better is to disable the DPI scaling by the custom sizing option:

[image]

Comment: Disabling DPI scaling (the second option) worked perfectly for me.  Thank you so much, was driving me crazy!!

Comment: Should it be 100% or higher?

Answer (score 11):

The blurry text is caused by the new [DPI scaling which is added in 8.1](http://blogs.windows.com/windows/b/extremewindows/archive/2013/07/15/windows-8-1-dpi-scaling-enhancements.aspx).

Set the size back to 100% and this fixes the issue.

[image]

Comment: Setting the size back to 100% strains my eyes thats the reason why i changed the size in the first place, I have found the solution thats disabling auto DPI scalling, look at my updated answer!

Comment: This is not new in Windows 8.1 -- display scaling has been with us since at least Vista. And a Surface and similar device really needs scaling, which worked just fine on 8.0. I think there must be more to this story, because 125% scaling in 8.0 was fine (and necessary); 8.1 is all fuzzy.

Comment: in 8.1 the scaling was changed to make it independent for each monitor. Vista till 8.0 the setting was applied for all monitors.